# How to redirect to external url using .push redux-router?

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, redux-router

I have `Card` which is redirecting on external URL on click. But instead of using `location.href`, I need to use `redux-router`'s `.push` command. How can I do this?

Simple example of the code:

```
<Card 

return (
  title={props.title}
  onClick={() => {
    location.href='www.example.com'
  }}
)
```

If I use this `props.navigate('www.example.com')` it is returning the URL like a parameter on the localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `Link` or `history.push` from react-router to redirect to an external site. You can use `window.location.href` or `window.location.replace`.

From [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/258#issuecomment-202623834):

> We don't support redirecting out of domain period. In general you should handle redirects to external URLs separately.

From [Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147#issuecomment-113180174):

> `<Link/>` is a router-aware anchor, if you want to link to an external site, use an `<a/>`.

#### Edit:

[Redux-Router](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router/blob/1a302fb057f37b4a388793b531ddddd38051900d/package.json#L56) uses `history` and `react-router` packages internally, so external redirects would not be possible with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make whole card clickable you also try -

`<a href="www.example.com" target="_blank"><Card /></a>`

Since you are trying to move out of the current application, so it does not matter if you are using react router or not.

Comment: This is a simple example of the code, i am mapping data with multiple cards, and the url is changing depending of the card so i cant do this.

Comment: Can you create an example on http://codesandbox.io/?